# select duplicate combination of columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that some records in my database are in duplicates for the same date in some columns. I need to find out these duplicates and the number of times they have been duplicated so I have written this query:

```
select tran_date,foracid, TRAN_PARTICULAR,part_tran_type, tran_amt, count(*) as COUNTS 
from tbaadm.htd,tbaadm.gam 
where gam.acid=htd.acid and tran_particular like '%FEE%' 
AND tran_date between '03-Mar-2014' and '11-Mar-2014'
and htd.acid in(select gam.acid from tbaadm.gam where gam.acct_ownership<>'O')
GROUP BY  tran_date, foracid, TRAN_PARTICULAR, tran_particular, 
part_tran_type, tran_amt
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
order by 2 desc;
```

My count Columns is not correct because I can see at some point it points that the rows are 2 while I have one. Sometimes the rows are 10 while I only have one row for the same Combination.

How can I get the five columns which are in duplicate and the number of rows for the combination of the columns?

Comment: This will be impossible to work out if you do not show us some real data, how the query is aggregating and counting it, and what you actually expect.

Comment: Have you seen if the items in tbaadm.gam are unique by htd.gam? You are counting the cartesian product of the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tran_date, foracid, TRAN_PARTICULAR, part_tran_type, tran_amt, count(*) as COUNTS 
FROM tbaadm.htd, tbaadm.gam 
WHERE gam.acid=htd.acid and tran_particular like '%FEE%' 
  AND tran_date between '03-Mar-2014' and '11-Mar-2014'
  AND htd.acid IN (SELECT gam.acid FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE gam.acct_ownership <> 'O')
GROUP BY  tran_date, foracid, TRAN_PARTICULAR, part_tran_type, tran_amt
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```